# How to use older Font Awesome icons in Angular?

Tags: icons, font-awesome

I would like to use the font awesome icon for ship as shown in this example

https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=tryicons_fa-ship

However nowadays they show below icon

https://fontawesome.com/icons/ship

Let me know if there is any way to show older font awesome icons.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The FA-Page shows the latest icons (v5), but they still give access to v4 [here](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/) ([ship-icon](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/ship)). But keep in mind that you shouldn't use v4 & v5 together...

Comment: Thank you I tried this but it is showing the newer version only.

Comment: If it shows the new version, then of course you will also need to change your code to use FA4 instead of FA5.